# SQL count number of records in one set of data compared to another and present as a percentage

Tags: sql, join, count, distinct

I would like to count the number of unique records not matching on 2 key variables from Data B compared to Data A and present the result as a percentage of the total unique records in Data B.

```
Data A:              Data B:
    key1 key2          key1 key2
    1    a             1    a
    2    a             2    a
    2    b             2    b
    3    c             2    d
                       2    b
                       2    d
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
SELECT 100 * (SELECT count(DISTINCT b.key2)) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.key2)) as output
FROM dataA a LEFT JOIN dataB b
ON a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2 = b.key2
```

From the above data I expect to get the result of 1 / 4 where the numerator represents the (2, d) value from data B that doesn't exist in data A and the denominator is the unique records by key in Data B.  The code currently doesn't work now I've put DISTINCT in, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Specify the expected result too.

Comment: the result I'm expecting is 0.25 as a quarter of the unique records in Data B don't exist in Data A. I'm using Spark.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `DataA` does not contain duplicate rows, you must do a `LEFT` join of `DataB` to `DataA` and aggregate:

```
select avg(case when a.key1 is null then 1.0 else 0 end) output
from (select distinct * from DataB) b left join DataA a
on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2
```

If `DataA` may contain duplicate rows, then:

```
select avg(case when a.key1 is null then 1.0 else 0 end) output 
from (select distinct * from DataB) b 
left join (select distinct * from DataA) a
on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2dc3c8c575c612b0af89448dfdeb4796) (for MySql but it is standard SQL).
Result:

```
> | output |
> | -----: |
> | 0.2500 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This was tested on Microsoft SQL Server. I would expect it to work in Spark as well.

```
 SELECT
        100 * (Total - Matching) / Total
    FROM (
    SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM DataB) t) AS [Total],
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DataB.Key1, DataB.Key2 FROM DataB INNER JOIN DataA ON DataB.Key1 = DataA.Key1 AND DataA.Key2 = DataB.Key2 ) u) AS [Matching]) v
```

Comment: Where are the t, u & v used?  Are they necessary?

Comment: They are necessary (at least as I wrote the query). They do nothing except provide a name for the query so I can use a select count against it. The letter names are arbitrary, and you can name it whatever you like.

Comment: Is there a missing closing bracket )?

Comment: I have run the query successfully in SQL Server Management Studio, so I don't think so.